# Is the performance of Persistent HTTP ALWAYS better than a non-persistent HTTP?

Tags: http

I was programming `HTTP 1.0` and `HTTP 1.1` for a college assignment.
Is there any possibility that a non persistent connection be better than a persistent one?

Comment: Are you talking about HTTP keep alives?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441075/pros-and-cons-of-keep-alive-from-web-server-side and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection.